# Codeigniter - Getting Internal Server error when trying to post with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I ve been trying to post something using ajax but I m getting a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. All other forms on the site using ajax work this is the only one that's giving the error. Not sure what is going on ... maybe someone will notice something I m not.

jQuery
(user_id is already defined in the view. alert returns everything I need to pass to the controller)

```
$('.one_add').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formID = $(this).attr('id');
            var formIDSplit = formID.split('-');
            var oneID = formIDSplit[1];

            var url = $('.one-link-'+oneID).val();
            var desc = $('.one-link-desc-'+oneID).val();

            $.post(base_url + "index.php/home/one_link", { user_id : user_id, one_id : oneID, desc : desc, url : url  }, function(data)
            {
            }, "json");

//              alert(user_id+'-'+oneID+'-'+desc+'-'+url);
});
```

The form

```
 <?php
      $attributes = array('class' => 'one_add', 'id' => 'add-'.$job->id.'');
      echo form_open('ajax/add_one_link', $attributes ); ?>
      <input type="text" class="one-link-<? echo $job->id; ?>" value="Url" />
      <input type="text" class="one-link-desc-<? echo $job->id; ?>" value="Description" />
      <button type="submit">Go!</button>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The controller function

```
function one_link()
    {
            $this->load->model('one_add_model');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'trim|required|xss_clean|strtolower');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'trim|required|xss_clean|strtolower');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('one_id', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

            $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
            $url = $this->input->post('url');
            $desc = $this->input->post('desc');
            $one_id = $this->input->post('one_id');

            $this->one_add_model->add_url($user_id, $url, $desc, $one_id);
    }
```

The model

```
function add_url($user_id, $url, $desc, $one_id);
{
     $query_str = "INSERT INTO one_add (`user_id`, `url`, `desc`, `one_id` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
     $this->db->query( $query_str, array($user_id, $url, $desc, $one_id) );
}
```

Comment: Yes, error messages are turned on. This is the only form that's causing problems. I did a few tests with other forms where I broke something on purpose and it gave error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was finally showing

```
Message:  Undefined property: Home::$form_validation
```

And I just loaded the form validaton which was not loaded. But it was in another controller and was causing the same error. Not sure what happened ... but it works now.

```
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **;** from add_url function definition

change

```
function add_url($user_id, $url, $desc, $one_id);
```

to

```
function add_url($user_id, $url, $desc, $one_id)
```

Comment: Any chance you have got some other syntax errors on the controller or model?

Comment: The model has only one function, so there's not too much code and it looks fine to me. And everything is working fine in the controller other than this one form.